# Optimize Filesize export from Premiere CS3

Tags: premiere, compression, quicktime

After screen capturing a video and editing it with Premiere CS3*, I'd like some help optimizing the Quicktime filesize. I was wondering if I can get the ratio back to 1:1 at least.

I have tried to best match my project settings to my original video type, but when I export my edit, the filesize increases from 55mb (10min) to 963mb (7min).

**Original video Settings**

- H.264 Codec / AAC 44.1khz, 448kbps Audio
- 1280*720 @ 25fps
- VBR Bitrate (many still frames are present), High quality, High Profile

**Premiere Project Settings**

- HDV 720p Preset
- 1280*720, 25fps
- No fields (Progressive scan)
- Video Rendering Setting: *Maximum Bit Depth (unchecked),* Optimize Stills (checked)

**Movie Export Settings**

- H.264
- 1280*720, 25fps
- Millions of Colours
- Quality 86% (don't understand!)
- Data Rate: Recompress - Always (checked) *or Maintain Data Rate (unchecked)*
  *Limit Data Rate: (unavailable)*

Keyframe and Rendering:

- Bit Depth: Use Project Settings (checked)/ *8-bit (unchecked)/ Maximum (unchecked)*
- Fields: No Fields (Progressive Scan)/ *Lower Field First (unchecked)/ Upper Field First (unchecked)*
  *- De-interlace Video Footage (unchecked)*
- Optimize Stills (checked).

*Apologies for using outdated software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now solved this problem. I was using Export > Movie, when I needed to go to Adobe Media Encoder to find more extensive options. I kept most settings the same, but believe turning 'Bitrate' off may have decreased the data rate. I got the filesize down to around 120mb, which is much better.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpbCnsyqT9E&index=1&list=LLH33Qv2Js0HzGcLnTYIWkNw) helped me find the Adobe Media Encoder.